# Best GNU Find Replacement

Tags: find, command-line-interface, ack, ag, ripgrep

I'm looking for a better find. The reason is that the find user interface is unintuitive to me (in particular, the pruning / -print style) and difficult to wrap in a function due to strict requirements on argument ordering. locate / updatedb isn't flexible enough to use instead. Would anyone care to share their example find wrappers or find alternatives (command line only, please)?

Here's an example of what I find to be unintuitive usage:

```
find dir_a dir_b \( -path dir_a/.git -o -path dir_b/out \) -prune -o \( -type f -o -type l \)
```

Specifying directories before options is strange to me and the syntax for pruning is easily forgotten. (Some programs use a --exclude option instead.) I recognize this is a picky point.

Here's my best attempt at specifying some defaults without losing much functionality:

```
f()
{
  # The trouble is that -regextype must appear after path but before expression.
  # HACK: "-D debugopts" unsupported and -[HLPO] options assumed to before dirs.
  local a=()
  while [[ -n "$1" ]] && ( [[ ! "${1:0:1}" =~ [-!(),] ]] || [[ "${1:0:2}" =~ -[HLPO] ]] )
  do
    a+=("$1")

    # Eliminate arg from @.
    shift
  done

  find -O3 "${a[@]}" -nowarn -regextype egrep "$@"
}
```

It seems silly to require a perfect understanding of all options in the program to be able to wrap it up with some defaults and not lose functionality / compatibility with plain find.

I'm guessing I won't fine anything as standard as GNU find, but there might be something better, albeit lesser known.

**Update (2013-11-26):**

- At Itay's suggestion, I used [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) for about a year. It works very well for at least 95% of my searches.
- I recently discovered [Ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), which is a fast version of ack. It's been working well for the past few weeks.

**Update (2014-11-23):**

I highly recommend [Ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher). It works great. There are still many times Find is necessary and for that I continue to seek a nice replacement. Although unquestionably useful, Find's interface is very dated and unnecessarily difficult in my opinion.

**Update (2017-08-04):**

I now most highly recommend [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) as an indispensable Ag replacement. It's a very new tool but it's support for .gitignore files greatly surpasses Ag and in all other ways it is equivalent or better. I continue to search for a Find replacement.

**Update (2021-11-28):**

I continue to use and love [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) which meets most of my needs. For everything else, I use a mixture of find and [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd).

Comment: The _strict requirements on argument ordering_ are not very clear, since you invoke `find` with `-O3` which may evaluate the tests in a different order.

Comment: Xargs with Find is somewhat usefull but I use File::Find from Perl.

Comment: @C2H5OH, when I mentioned strict ordering, I meant that which is imposed by find itself. If the ordering isn't as expected, find will error out. I recognize optimization may internally change ordering, but that's fine.

Comment: @starbolin, do you normally invoke from the command line? I tagged the post with bash to hint that I'm looking for options available from the shell. I've updated the original post to make this clear.

Comment: Please give an example where `find` does not work for you. I don't see the point of trying to replace a properly working, standard, well know GNU util with something adhoc.

Comment: @abc, there is no such example. find works for me but I seek an alternative that is easier to use and easier to script. I've my question to provide greater clarity.

Comment: It's really hard to imagine how could `locate` not be flexible enough, considering that you can process its output with sed, AWK, Perl/Python/Ruby or even shell scripting.

Comment: @C2H5OH, locate is actually quite primitive compared to find in every way except indexing. Locate doesn't maintain a lot of key file attributes such as type, timestamps, permissions, and owner. find also has a lot of really nice functions to operate on files that locate would require an additional xargs sh invocation and a fair amount of scripting to support. I'm seeking a find replacement, not seeking to write one :)

Comment: +1 At the beginning, I think _Why do you need other tools, when there is find_. But I recognized immediately that `find` is not very user friendly, when condition is complex.

Comment: When conditions are complex, conditions are complex. Within the set of *good* tools you will find tools that handles a specific subset of complex conditions well and simply, and tools that are flexible, but require configuration and understanding of the complexity. You cannot have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: Why not just write a wrapper around find?

Comment: @helpermethod, as mentioned in the question, it's quite difficult to wrap in a function due to strict requirements on argument ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try [Ack](http://betterthangrep.com/), which is a replacement for both `find` and `grep`, optimized for working with source-code trees.

Comment: Looks neat. I'll try it out and follow-up.

Comment: Since trying out Ack, I've come to the realization that what I really want is Find with a different UI. That said, I've found Ack to be a useful alternative for most of my needs.

Comment: I recently switched from Ack to Ag (https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) which seems to be a good bit faster.